# Unresolved dependency issue when compiling spark project with sbt

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to compile with `sbt 0.13.8` a very simple spark project whose only function is

**Test.scala**

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val logFile = "YOUR_SPARK_HOME/README.md" // Should be some file on your system
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
    val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
    val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
    println("Lines with a: %s, Lines with b: %s".format(numAs, numBs))
  }
}
```

The **build.sbt** file in the projet root is as follows:

```
name := "Test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Apache Repository" at "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/",
  "Cloudera Repository" at "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/",
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("public")
)
```

The error return by `sbt compile` is:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: oro#oro;2.0.8: configuration not found in oro#oro;2.0.8: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11;1.5.2 compile
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      oro:oro:2.0.8
[warn]        +- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:1.5.2 (/home/osboxes/Documents/bookings/Test/build.sbt#L7-8)
[warn]        +- default:test_2.11:1.0
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: oro#oro;2.0.8: configuration not found in oro#oro;2.0.8: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11;1.5.2 compile
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:291)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:188)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:165)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:132)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:127)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:124)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:155)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:165)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1369)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1365)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$87.apply(Defaults.scala:1399)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$87.apply(Defaults.scala:1397)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:37)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1402)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1396)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:60)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1419)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1348)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1310)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: oro#oro;2.0.8: configuration not found in oro#oro;2.0.8: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11;1.5.2 compile
```

How could I solve this dependency issue?

**EDIT**

I have followed the @mark91's advice:

- change scala version to `2.10.5`
- change the spark dependency to `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.2.0-cdh5.3.2" % "provided"`.

However I still get an unresolved dependency in org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4 :

```
 [error] sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4: configuration not found in org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.10;1.2.0-cdh5.3.2 compile
```

Do you have any idea of why I get this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your problem is that Spark is written with Scala 2.10. So you should use version 2.10 of Scala instead of 2.11.

Example:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.2.0-cdh5.3.2" % "provided"


resolvers += "Cloudera Repository" at "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/"
```

Comment: When I use Scala 2.10 (precisely 2.10.4), I get the some error. Plus, two additional unresolved dependencies: `org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4` and `org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.4`

Comment: Still an issue with your new solution: `[error] sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4: configuration not found in org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.10;1.2.0-cdh5.3.2 compile
`

Comment: It looks quite strange to me...I'm using that file ad it compiles with success...

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar dependency issue and solved it by reloading plugins and updating dependencies. I think your dependency issue is due to Ivy cache. Normally, if no dependency management configuration has changed since the last successful resolution and the retrieved files are still present, sbt does not ask Ivy to perform resolution.

Try running:

```
sbt reload plugins
sbt update
sbt reload
```

If that doesn't work, follow instructions on http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Dependency-Management-Flow.html

Comment: 1.x series docs can be found here: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Dependency-Management-Flow.html

Answer (score 1):

Same Reason as @mgaido: Using different version of Scala cause this problem.
But sometime, even we change later to correct version of scala, our cache still might have the older one. In that case we can delete `~/.ivy2` folder.